# Implement Atmosphere security in C# using Restsharp

Tags: c#, authentication, restsharp

I do have an Rest end point and the specification request this Atmosphere Realm:

Authorization  :  Atmosphere realm=http://atmosphere,atmosphere_app_id=***-1xxxxx9xx5u2AlGCdDyXWx4x

How do I implement the Atmosphere concept in Restsharp?

Comment: Hi there! What is your actual problem? Do you have some code to show? Also, please note, that StackOverflow is _not_ a code-writing service.

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO, you should specify your problem and what you tried already.